# Mount Windows public share on Linux without username & password

Tags: linux, linux-networking, samba, network-share

I am using a backup script to first make a mysql dump file on a linux box and then copy it to a windows network share. This works fine if the network share has a username and password asscociated with it however this new share has no user /password protection and I cant seem to mount this new share on the linux box. Keep getting "permission denied". If I leave out the username / password from the mount.cifs command it defaults to the linux username and prompts for password which never works as it is not set up on the windows share. I dont have access to the Windows server to change this.

Is there a way to mount this new share without username and password?

Comment: When you say the new share has no user /password protection, do you mean the share permissions are set to Everyone Allow Full? What are the NTFS permissions are on the share?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using the option **guest** ? Or **user=,password=** ?

But I'm affraid you can't if the share is not allowed to *Everyone*

Comment: Yes, tried that but would not work.

Comment: However, just a thought, The Linux username and password does not exist on the domain but will use a username and password that does to see if that makes a difference even though Everyone access has been enabled on the Windows folder

Comment: user=, password= works perfectly

Comment: user=guest  password=guest worked here

Comment: @SledgehammerPL not work. Still ask my password of root.

Comment: @SledgehammerPL this worked for my setup